# How do you change the source list of a customlist field in SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to change the source list of one customlist field for an item, when a value on another list is selected. For example if list one is selected as "dairy", I want the options in list two to be "milk, yogurt, etc.", but if I chose "protein", I want the options in list two to be "eggs, steak, etc.".

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope Public
 */

define(['N/record'], function (r){
    function configureRecyclingDropDownLists(context) {
        var curRecord = context.currentRecord;
        var ddl1Value = curRecord.getValue({
            fieldid: "custitem_recycling_categories"
        });
        var custListRec;
        switch (ddl1Value) {
            case 'Ferrous (steel)':
                var custListRecId = "customlist_ferrous_child_category";
                //custListRec = r.load({type: r.Type.customlist, id: customlist_ferrous_child_category});
                break;  
            case 'Non-Ferrous (aluminum)':
                var custListRecId = "customlist_non_ferrous_child_category";
                //custListRec = r.load({type: r.Type.customlist, id: customlist_non_ferrous_child_category});
                break;
        }
        curRecord.setValue({
            fieldid: "custitem_recycling_sub_category",
            sublistId: custListRecId,
            ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
    }

    return{
        fieldChanged: configureRecyclingDropDownLists
    };

});
```

This is my current attempt. I think that "setValue" should maybe be "setSublist", but when trying that did not work either. The commented out lines for each case was my first attempt where I was setting the value (curRecord field value) equal to the custListRec.value, but that did not seem correct either.

Any direction in how I could progress would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you use the OOB functionality that NetSuite provides for this by using dependant drop downs? See :https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N2840468.html

Comment: @ehcanadian I didn't know about that, thanks! that sounds like the right way to do it, however when I go to implement this on the list field, it gives me no options for "filter using". So I thought maybe the field that is the condition of the filtering should be the source list, but still no options are showing.

Comment: **Update:** I have learned that "Note: Filtering applies only to lists of records. It does not apply to custom lists." Therefore unfortunately this is not an option for me. 
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N2840153.html

Comment: Hey Cameron, have you tried using Custom Records? Enter all of the items with their corresponding categories and source them to a custom field. Have them filtered by `custitem_recycling_categories`